# size of a struct in c equals to 1

Tags: c, struct

For some reason if I try to get the actual size of `mystruct` I keep getting size 1.

I know that `mystruct` is holding the data cause I can dump it out and everything is in `mystruct`.

What could be the reason of getting size 1?
Thanks

```
// fragments of my code
struct mystruct {
    char *raw;
    int  count;
};

struct counter {
    int total; // = 30
}

static struct mystruct **proc()
{
    int i = 0;
    gchar *key,*val;
    struct mystruct **a_struct;
    struct counter c;

    a_struct = (struct mystruct **)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct *)*c.total);
    while (table (&iter, (gpointer) &key, (gpointer) &val)) {

        a_struct[i] = (struct mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
        a_struct[i]->raw = (char*)key;
        a_struct[i++]->count = (int)val;

    }

    size_t l = sizeof(a_struct) / sizeof(struct mystruct*);
    printf("%d",l); // outputs 1
}
```

Comment: Also, use %zu instead of %d format specifier for size_t.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing a couple things wrong.  First, you're taking `sizeof(a_struct)` which is going to be the size of a pointer (since that's what `a_struct` is) and then dividing by the size of another pointer.  Guaranteed 1.

Besides that, why are you doing a division at all?  What I think you want is:

```
size_t l = sizeof(struct mystruct);
```

or

```
size_t l = sizeof(**a_struct);
```

Edit:

I think I see the reason for your division now; you're trying to find the size of that array.  That's not going to work - `sizeof` can only work at compile time in C (with some special exceptions in C99 which don't apply to your code), so it can't figure out the size of a dynamic array like that.

Comment: "`sizeof` can only work at compile time in C"... Not exactly true in C99, since in C99 `sizeof` can be used with VLAs, in which case it works at run-time.

Comment: @AndreyT, good call.  That doesn't apply to the dynamic-array-from-malloc approach of the OP's code though.

Answer (score 4):

you're dividing the size of a pointer by the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`a_struct` is a double pointer to `struct mystruct`.
`struct mystruct *` is a pointer to `struct mystruct`.

Both there sizes will be same.

Do this `size_t l = sizeof(struct mystruct);`

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the size of two pointers and dividing one by the other,

```
size_t l = sizeof(a_struct) / sizeof(struct mystruct*);
```

`a_struct` is declared as `struct mystruct **a_struct` so this is the same as saying

```
size_t l = sizeof(struct mystruct **) / sizeof(struct mystruct*);
```

since all pointers have the same size, ** is the same size as *, so this will always evaluate to 1.

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to print out here, the size of `a_struct` ? or the total allocation size?  The size of `a_struct` is just `c.total`, the total allocation is the sum of all of the values that you passed to malloc.